# Drupal 7: multiupload with file entity fields support

Tags: drupal-7, filefield, multifile-uploader

Is there a way to have a multifileupload with "file entity"/"file entity inline" support?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, multiple upload is not available in Drupal out of the box. But there are several contributed modules which provides that feature - check out this comparison list: [Multiple file upload for node](http://groups.drupal.org/node/155764).

For images I use [Plup](http://drupal.org/project/plup) module and it works just fine.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "custom" field. I'm currently using Pulp module with field type "image" (both content type and field are custom in sense that I created them via CCK), and it works practically perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with 
http://drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676 Media Multiselect module
media-2.x-dev
file_entity-2.x-dev
http://drupal.org/project/plupload
http://drupal.org/project/multiform

Note: this doesn't use the file_entity_inline combo, but each file will have an edit button next to it.